# Is there an easy way to get twitter mentions using a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, twitter, sinatra, tweetstream, grackle

I've tried using the gem [twitter](https://github.com/sferik/twitter), [grackle](https://github.com/ntreadway/grackle), and [TweetStream](https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream) but I can't figure out how to get a stream of a users @mentions.

I just can't figure out how to put together a bit of code that says 'get all mentions to user'. (and I want to tap into the @mention, not just search twitter for a username)

I'm using Sinatra :: I've got it all up and running :: I can post to a feed, pull specific status's and so on. Getting @mentions is eluding me.

Comment: Perhaps the GET statuses/mentions page on dev.twitter will be of help:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/mentions

Answer (score 2):

I only use the [oauth](https://github.com/oauth/oauth-ruby) gem but this is how you can do it.
Since you can post feed, I guess you have the process till the access_token.

```
>> response = access_token.get('http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/mentions.json')
>> JSON.parse(response.body)
#=> Array of Hashes with all the info
```

By the way, I see a function already included in the [Twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter/blob/master/lib/twitter/tweet.rb) source code.

**tweet.rb**

```
# @note Must include entities in your request for this method to work
# @return [Array<Twitter::Entity::UserMention>]
def user_mentions
  @user_mentions ||= entities(Twitter::Entity::UserMention, :user_mentions)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the search/tweets API from Twitter and set q: "@USERNAME" which will find the tweets that mention your user.